# Is there a performance or storage difference to consider when using Date vs DateTime?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, performance

When using SQL Server & ASP.NET, is there a performance / storage consideration when using `Date` vs `DateTime`?

Even if I don't need it, I've been using `DateTime` for most things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DateTime takes 8 bytes per value

Date is 3 bytes.

I can't speak for low level performance; however in general we've found it a mistake to store values as DateTime by default.  Sooner or later you run into the UTC issue and have to start working out offsets for dates that have 00:00:00.000 in the time portion!

If you're just storing dates I'd stick to the Date datatype; you'll fit more rows per page and save yourself a lot of hassle

Comment: This also depends on what the context of "date" is and if it needs to be TZ-aware (my Friday might not be your Friday). Not that storing everything as UTC is much better... as it still doesn't capture the TZ itself. There is a `DATETIMEOFFSET` type as well; however, I do not know how it maps to .NET :(

Comment: @Click-Rex can you explain your context  please?

Comment: DateTime is just "local time" - it has no notion of timezone presentation.  It means that you have to know what timezone it was written in to enable you to accurately decode it.  There are a gamut of problems like daylight saving buried in there too.  That's where the comment about UTC comes in - all apps would cook dates into UTC for storage, and back to local time for display.  Sounds easy?  Not really - its actually quite hard to get all apps to do this without lots of deliberate effort and testing.  DateTimeOffset type was introduced to try and alleviate the problem.

Comment: **DateTime is just "local time"** This is the server time, location of Database server.

Comment: @PankajGarg It's whatever you make it out to be... I choose UTC always. It's the least bad of the approaches when using DateTime, IMOHO. (Alternate to actually storing the TZ/offset, which can just be a PITA to deal with.)

Comment: Yeah I agree pst, we went with UTC too.  In introducing the Offset notion, all they did was change the problem of UTC translation into adding timezone to all date/time encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how many rows you're storing, and what you're using it for.  Date is 3 bytes, DateTime is 8 bytes.  Can quickly add up when you have billions of rows of data, or are using it for an index.  Naturally there is a difference in the resolution of the value stored too.  There are other date-types between date and datetime too such as smalldatetime that are more compact, again with different compromises.

[SQL Date/Time Types Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Considerations:

- Performance: less bits for date-type **means** more rows per sql page (data page or index page) **means** less pages to be read while executing query
- Compatibility: `DATE` type was introduced in SQL Server 2008, so your app it's not compatibile with SQL Server 2005 any more
- .NET: no `Date` Class in .NET - `DATE` is converted into `DateTime` .NET Class
- LINQ: LINQ2SQL (and SQL Metal tool) goes well with `DATE` SQL type
- You may crop hours and minutes from `DATETIME` doing `CAST(@myDateTimeParam AS DATE)`

From my experience: I like this new type and had no problems with it while programming T-SQL or C#

Be aware of this (mixing data types for date on comparition):

```
DECLARE @startDay DATE = '2012-04-11' -- day
DECLARE @endDay DATE = '2012-04-13' -- day
DECLARE @eventTime DATETIME = '2012-04-13 12:00' -- point in time (noon)

IF @eventTime BETWEEN @startDay AND @endDay PRINT 'In period.' ELSE PRINT 'Not in period!'
```

Result is:

```
Not in period!
```

On `BETWEEN` comparition `@endDay` was casted down to `DATETIME` (to point in time; the common type with `@eventTime`), I guess - what gives unintuitive result.

Compare with:

```
DECLARE @startDay DATE = '2012-04-11' -- day
DECLARE @endDay DATE = '2012-04-13' -- day
DECLARE @eventTime DATE = '2012-04-13' -- day

IF @eventTime BETWEEN @startDay AND @endDay PRINT 'In period.' ELSE PRINT 'Not in period!'
```

Result:

```
In period.
```

And with it:

```
DECLARE @startDay DATETIME = '2012-04-11' -- day, but point in time in fact 00:00.000
DECLARE @endDay DATETIME = '2012-04-13' -- day, but point in time in fact 00:00.000
DECLARE @eventTime DATETIME = '2012-04-13' -- day, but point in time in fact 00:00.000

IF @eventTime BETWEEN @startDay AND @endDay PRINT 'In period.' ELSE PRINT 'Not in period!'
```

Result:

```
In period.
```